# Estimating heteroscedasticity in linear mixed effects model?

Tags: lme4-nlme, heteroscedasticity

I have a dataset with columns: (subject, method, recordingDate, side), which I am modelling in R using lme4:

```
modelA.full <- lmer(ASSR ~ Method + Side + (1|subject/side) + (1|recordingDate/method) + (1|subject/method), data = Data, REML = FALSE);
```

In the above, the point is to model recordingDate & subject as random factors, and method & side as fixed, and I am expecting interactions between subject & side, recordingDate & method and subject & method.

However, I would like to test whether the unexplained variance is larger for different values of 'method'. How do I include that in my model?

I apologize if there is anything missing in the above - I am rather new to R.